# Can anyone show me some examples of NSpec being used to test controllers (and other aspects of MVC site)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, bdd, nspec

I'm starting working with NSpec but would love a few pointers on the right way to use it to spec or test my controllers.  Basically a few examples would go a very long way. Are there any example projects out there? All help would be appreciated.

Richard.

Comment: Have you look at SpecFlow? http://www.specflow.org/

Comment: Hi, yes, i'm planning on using specflow for my acceptance/integration tests, but I was of the understanding that nspec would be better for testing components - this seems to be the common wisdom i've read about in the RSpec book, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why yes! The tests suite that follows is from a reference implementation, there are 4 unique mvc applications that all use NSpec as their test suite.  Definitely check them out [here](https://github.com/amirrajan/Oak/tree/master/Sample%20Apps).

Here is one of the tests.  This specification verifies a login page and a registration page.  For a website.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NSpec;
using BorrowedGames.Controllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BorrowedGames.Tests.Controllers
{
  class describe_AccountController : _borrowed_games
  {
    AccountController controller;

    dynamic user;

    bool authenticated;

    void before_each()
    {
      controller = new AccountController();

      controller.Authenticate = s =>
      {
        authenticated = true;

        SetCurrentUser(controller, Users.ForEmail(s).Id);
      };
    }

    void logging_in()
    {
      context["requesting login page"] = () =>
      {
        act = () => result = controller.LogOn();

        it["returns login page"] = () => 
          (result as object).should_cast_to<ViewResult>();
      };

      context["authenticating"] = () =>
      {
        act = () => result = controller.LogOn(new
        {
          Email = "user@example.com",
          Password = "password",
          RedirectUrl = null as string
        });

        context["user exists"] = () =>
        {
          before = () => 
            user = GivenUser("user@example.com", null, "password");

          it["authenicates user"] = () =>
            authenticated.should_be_true();

          it["redirects to home page"] = () => 
            (result.Url as string).should_be("/");

          it["sets user in session"] = () =>
            (controller.UserId()).should_be((decimal)user);
        };

        context["user exists, password doesn't match"] = () =>
        {
          before = () => 
            GivenUser("user@example.com", null, "other");

          it["returns invalid login"] = () => 
            (result.ViewBag.Flash as string).should_be("Login failed.");
        };

        context["user does not exist"] = () =>
        {
          it["returns invalid login"] = () => 
            (result.ViewBag.Flash as string).should_be("Login failed.");
        };
      };
    }

    void registering_for_site()
    {
      context["requesting registration page"] = () =>
      {
        act = () => result = controller.Register();

        it["returns view"] = () => 
          (result as object).should_cast_to<ViewResult>();
      };

      context["user registers"] = () =>
      {
        act = () =>
        {
          result = controller.Register(new
          {
            Email = "user@example.com",
            Password = "password",
            PasswordConfirmation = "password"
          });

          user = Users.All().First().Id;
        };

        it["logs in user"] = () => 
          (result.Url as string).should_be("/");

        it["authenticates user"] = () => 
          authenticated.should_be_true();

        it["sets user in session"] = () =>
          ((decimal)controller.UserId()).should_be((decimal)user);

        context["user name is taken"] = () =>
        {
          before = () => GivenUser("user@example.com");

          it["return error stating that user name is taken"] = () =>
            (result.ViewBag.Flash as string).should_be("Email is unavailable.");
        };
      };

      context["registration is invalid"] = () =>
      {
        act = () => result = 
          controller.Register(new 
          { 
            Email = default(string), 
            Password = default(string) 
          });

        it["returns error stating that email is required."] = () =>
          (result.ViewBag.Flash as string).should_be("Email is required.");
      };
    }
  }
}
```